# how to ignore spaces in csv file with batch script

Tags: excel, csv, batch-file

I got a batch script for splitting one field into multiple tokens to use them
if the line in csv file is like:

```
token1,token2,token3,"first token;second token ;third token;fourth token"
```

and `first token;second token ;third token;fourth token` represents 1 column in the actual excel sheet

I want to split that column and reserve the spaces 
i.e

I want to set string1=first token
        and string2=second token

this is the batch I'm using

```
set "string=%%m"

set /a count=0


for %%c in (%%m) do (
    set /a count+=1
    set "variable!count!=%%c"
)
```

How can I do that??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you take it from here?

```
C:>type tokfile.bat
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /F "usebackq delims=, tokens=1,2,3,4,5" %%a IN (`type tokfile.txt`) DO (
    ECHO %%a
    ECHO %%b
    ECHO %%c
    ECHO %%d

    SET G=%%d
    SET GG=!G:~1,-1!

    ECHO G is !G!
    ECHO GG is !GG!

    FOR /F "delims=; tokens=1,2,3,4" %%s IN (%%d) DO (
        ECHO %%s
        ECHO %%t
        ECHO %%u
        ECHO %%v
    )
)

EXIT /B 0
```

The data file:

```
C:>type tokfile.txt
token1,token2,token3,"first token;second token ;third token;fourth token"
```

The output:

```
10:57:30.03  C:\Users\pwatson\bin
C:>tokfile.bat
token1
token2
token3
"first token;second token ;third token;fourth token"
G is "first token;second token ;third token;fourth token"
GG is first token;second token ;third token;fourth token
first token
second token
third token
fourth token
```